# why i have black rectangles on my photo?

Tags: noise, sony-alpha

Original photo
[image: black rectangles example]

Edited photo to better show rectangles
[image]

sony a6000     
iso 100     
3.2    
f/5     
sigma 60 mm (90mm for aps-c)

Comment: Those are jpeg images. At high compression levels jpeg shows compression artefacts which can look exactly like that. Does the same happen when you shoot in raw and don't save as jpeg? That said... they look suspiciously point.symmetric wrt the center of the image... can it be related to AF points or similar?

Comment: Also, do they occur on other photos, with a different camera and the same lens or with a different lens on the same camera?

Comment: Welcome to Sonyworld, where noise reduction is more important than an accurate depiction of the scene.

Comment: I dont have another lenses. and it's just in the jpegs. in the realy dark ones. some of them dont have the rectangless in the middle, just on top and bottom. but the raws are clean.

Comment: @Tsvi It's not really clear what answer you're seeking. If you're shooting RAW+JPEG and the RAWs are clean, while the JPEGs have artifacts, the cause is most likely somewhere in the JPEG processing pipeline. Anything more specific would require more detailed knowledge of the algorithms involved. (Why do the artifacts appear to be symmetric?)

Answer (score 2):

JPEG compression artefacts.  Choose a different compression setting, or export RAW.

Comment: This doesn't explain why the artifacts appear in a symmetric pattern.

Comment: As xiota says above, it could be an issue in the JPEG pipeline. If something like lens correction is being applied to JPEGs (before compression), that could easily cause symmetrical distortions which might interact with bugs in other parts of the algorithm, or simply cause slightly darker regions. A software problem seems the most likely cause: evidently relating to location in the image rather than light or color levels. Playing with compression levels and varying other settings might give a clue, but probably only Sony knows the truth.